# Spacemacs hybrid line numbers

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

How do I get hybrid line numbering (relative line numbers, but the current line shows the absolute line number instead of 0) in spacemacs for all files?

I tried setting relative line numbers in user-config but that doesn't seem to be working, and can't figure out how to replace the 0 in relative mode either:

```
(global-linum-mode)
(setq-default dotspacemacs-line-numbers 'relative)
```

Comment: FYI http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19532/hybrid-line-number-mode-in-emacs is a similar question (but using  https://github.com/coldnew/linum-relative rather than this `dotspacemacs-line-numbers` feature).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `dotspacemacs-line-numbers` variable already exists in your `.spacemacs`, in the `dotspacemacs/init` function. If it is not the case you can update your `.spacemacs` to the last template with the help of `SPC f e D`.

Change its value to `'relative`, as in:

```
;; If non nil line numbers are turned on in all `prog-mode' and `text-mode'
;; derivatives. If set to `relative', also turns on relative line numbers.
;; (default nil)
dotspacemacs-line-numbers 'relative
```

Then remove the two lines you added in your `dotspacemacs/user-config`. All you need is to change the variable as explained above, it will take care of applying the changes for you :-)